# IoC setup and issue with inherited class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm fairly new to the IoC pattern and I've hit an issue on the way the following should be setup.

I've got a Service class which has the following constructor:

```
public BookingService(IBookingRepository bookingRepository, IUnitRepository   unitRepository, IRateRepository rateRepository, IDiscountRepository discountRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.bookingRepository = bookingRepository;
        this.unitRepository = unitRepository;
        this.rateRepository = rateRepository;
        this.discountRepository = discountRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

Now I've got this working with my controllers like so:

```
private IBookingService _bookingService;

    public AdminBookingSurfaceController(IBookingService bookingService)
    {
        _bookingService = bookingService;
    }
```

Where I've got stuck is when using the BookingService in an inherited class from a Third Party framework (Umbraco).

This is the current constructor:

```
public class Freedom2BookTree : umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.BaseTree
{
    public Freedom2BookTree(string application)
        : base(application)
    {
    }
```

I wasn't sure how IoC would work with this, I tried like this but it didn't work:

As in, when I add the additional parameter the constructor never gets hit/called

```
public class Freedom2BookTree : umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.BaseTree
{
    private IBookingService _bookingService;
    public Freedom2BookTree(string application, IBookingService bookingService)
        : base(application)
    {
        _bookingService = bookingService;
    }
```

If anyone could lend some advice on how this should be done or if I'm looking at it in the wrong way, that would great :)

Many Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Why do you need the BookingService inside the third party component?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain myself well enough. Freedom2BookTree is my own class, I'm just inheriting from the Third Party Class which requires me to call the base constructor. My class then gets called from the Third Party framework. What the class does is let me build my own Node Tree, so i need to call the BookingService to get the data to build the custom node tree. Hope this clarify's things a little better. Thanks :)

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: What exactly "didn't work"? Also, this should be tagged "umbraco" or maybe "umbraco5", which are you using?

Comment: The constructor never gets called when I add the additional parameter. As soon as I remove its fine and gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that framework only executes a constructor with specific parameters.

You can make the `IBookingService` a property on the `Freedom2BookTree` and assign it outside of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion BlueChamelon, would you mind elaborating a bit more as I don't quite follow how it would tie into IoC... I'm currently using Ninject. Thanks :)

Comment: I have not used Ninject, but there are other ways to inject a dependency than through the constructor. One of the ways is to make it a property.

Comment: How does umbraco framework "know" about your new class (Freedom2BookTree)?

Comment: Thanks BlueChameleon. I think I follow what you mean now. I will research Property Injection in Ninject and see where I get :)

Comment: If property injection is not possible or is too cumbersome, you can user the Service Locator pattern to assign the value to the property from within the constructor. This amounts to something like _bookingService = Container.Resolve<IBookingService>(); while your constructor still only takes the original single parameter.

Comment: Thanks Facio Ratio, that's roughly what I ended up doing in the end :)