# Ninject Property Injection Setup Issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

This question relates to an answer to a question I asked earlier ([IoC setup and issue with inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488538/ioc-setup-and-issue-with-inherited-class)).

I've tried setting up property injection to overcome my issue in my other question however the object is always null.

My setup is as follows:

Class with Property and Inject Attribute

```
public class Freedom2BookTree : umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.BaseTree
{
    private IBookingService _bookingService;

    [Inject]
    public IBookingService BookingService
    {
        get { return _bookingService; }
        set { _bookingService = value; }
    }
```

Ninject code in Application Start

```
// Create Ninject DI kernel
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

// Register services with Ninject DI Container
kernel.Bind<IBookingService>().To<BookingService>().InRequestScope();

// Tell ASP.NET MVC 3 to use our Ninject DI Container
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

I'd really appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working by following the answer to this question:

[How do I inject into some generic asp.net http handler using Ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446737/how-do-i-inject-into-some-generic-asp-net-http-handler-using-ninject)